# Is it possible to add tooltips to individual polygons on a map shapefile? (Report Builder 3.0)

Tags: reporting-services, tooltip, shapefile

I have a report that maps sales to particular postal areas which works great. The only issue I'm having is it's not directly obvious exactly which area is which. The information exists in the file (see picture below) but I'm wondering if there is a way to have tooltips for each polygon that denote the area it represents.

I tried setting the expression for "tooltip" in the map properties dialog to the postal area field of my dataset but that only provided a tooltip for the entire map not the individual polygons. I'm hoping these some obvious property I'm missing or failing that some clever hack that can get the result.

If tooltips aren't possible is there a way to label each polygon? That might be a little too busy on the page but if it's the only option I'd like to give it a look and see if it's workable.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tooltip for individual polygons in the Map Polygon Properties. This will show up when you hover over a polygon in a report viewer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Obviously property I was missing. Called it! Cheers.